# ReferenceError getValuesOfAutofillInputs, Can't find variable: PaymentAutofillConfig

Tags: reactjs, facebook, webview, stripe-payments, instagram

We are facing the Reference error in our code since 2nd of June 2022 on our sentry logs.
Moreover its only happening on iOS (iphone) devices only..

Please find the link below to see the error:
https://sentry.io/share/issue/876e86524c96471b9524f70afb16faf7/

We are using `stripe` and `react-js` to create our app and could **not** find any such method inside our app or stripe code..

We have no clue of what it could be, plus searching `getValuesOfAutofillInputs` or `PaymentAutofillConfig` gives zero result on google too..

In our understanding it looks to be an issue on Facebook webview's (when we open link inside instagram or facebook apps)

Looking forward to hear if someone is facing this issue or to let us know where to report or create a issue for this ?

Comment: We've been getting this in our sentry logs as well, common thread is it's always facebook browser on iOS.  Seems like they're injecting some (bad) js into the page and it's blowing up.

Comment: Same here (via DataDog browser collector, not Sentry). It seems to have nothing to do with our code. First event (of many now) happened 2022-06-02 08:00

Comment: Hii thanks for informing, guys do you know where is would be best to create an issue for this ?

Comment: Same here, with the Instagram app

Comment: I am getting 1 error per very 5 seconds in my logs..  does it effect your functionality ? If not we can ignore it, right ?

Comment: Same problem here, Sentry is reporting the error in our app and comes from Instagram app browser, I guess they are trying to fill some fields with payment info.

Comment: Same here.  Very annoying error on Sentry and I'm getting it many times a day

Comment: We have ignored the error on sentry.. assuming it's not effecting any functionality 

Comment: A javascript error that shows up in an injected script block shouldn't affect the functionality of the page.  Of course, the thing it's supposed to be doing won't work either... but considering it's been injected I imagine it's attempting to iterate certain inputs on the screen and do something with them -- likely related to payment.

Comment: I did a search on github and found 2 hits for "getValuesOfAutofillInputs" in what appear to be generated js files -- heavily referencing "facebook utilities" -- the code is from years ago, so I imagine that routine has been around for a while, but providing a configuration is new, expected, and not always provided.

https://github.com/JonasAzevedo/asdigital_food4/blob/76bd09bb322b33e3524585c87a3e397f49d33810/TYME%20Food%20-%20ORDER%20NOW_files/platform.Extensions.js.download

Comment: Yeah we found this too, but we were not sure if it's related, as it appears to be a js script that's pushed to someone GitHub account, and I hardly believe Facebook would integrate any public script into there browser or something...

Comment: Nonetheless, it's the only reference that's present online publicly..

Answer (score 0):

As you have already searched for getValuesOfAutofillInputs and PaymentAutofillConfig without any results, it is possible that this issue might be related to how Facebook's webview handles autofill features for payment information.

Try this steps:

- Replicate the issue: Try to reproduce the issue on multiple iOS devices and different versions of the Facebook and Instagram apps.
- Test in other webviews: Test your app in other webview environments on iOS, such as within the Twitter app
- Debug in the iOS Simulator: You can use the iOS Simulator, available in Xcode, to debug the issue in a simulated iOS environment
- Report the issue to Facebook

In the meantime, consider providing your users with guidance on how to open your app links outside of Facebook or Instagram webviews to avoid encountering the error.